# Example of Baire Space

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Can anybody supply an example of a Baire Space, that is neither locally compact nor metrizable. I would be gratefull also for some references.

Comment: Some such examples were discussed in comments to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88483/every-space-is-almost-baire).

Answer (score 2):

As a trivial example, let $X,Y$ be Baire spaces with $X$ not locally compact and $Y$ not metrizable, and consider the disjoint union of $X,Y$.

Answer (score 2):

The [Sorgenfrey line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line) is one example. It is [not locally compact](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2009;task=show_msg;msg=4102.0001.0001) nor is it metrizable. [Here](http://www.ikhebeenvraag.be/mediastorage/FSDocument/69/SorgenfreyBaire.pdf) is a paper showing that it is a Baire space..